# What is the negative of a distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Suppose we know that A has a standard normal distribution, what would be the distribution of $-A$? Is it still a probability distribution at all?

This comes from a brownian motion problem I was working on, so suppose $W$ is a standard $BM$, so we know that $Wt - Ws \thicksim N(0, t-s)$ given $t\gt s$.
So know let $Y = -Wt$
$Yt - Ys = -Wt - (-Ws) = Ws - Wt$, so what would be the distribution of this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Also standard normal.

Comment: Since $f_A(-t) = f_A(t)$, $-A$ has the same distribution as $A$. This is true for any symmetric distribution.